# Azure Data Factory - Mapping in the copy activity

Tags: mapping, azure-data-factory, etl

I am using a copy activity to copy data from REST endpoint to a SQL database.
Everything seems to work as expected .. except one little caveat.
In the mapping tab, the field that maps as a boolean, I need it to go in as a "bit" or an "Int" ?
[image]

Can it be done for this one field only ? and if yes, what is approach ?  I do not want to disrupt the rest of the mapping that I got by "Import Mapping" - there are a lot of fields, so doing it by hand is not desirable.

P.S:  In response to the answer suggesting to use Type conversion settings, I do not have that !!  here is a screenshot

[image: No type conversion settings]

Answer (score 0):

- If this is the only Boolean column in your API response, then you can directly use this feature in the mapping which allows you to treat Boolean as integer.

[image]

- If there are other unknown Boolean columns which will also get affected and you do not want this, then manual transformations would be required to send the data as either `bit` or `int`.
- There might be no other way to do this other than the sink mapping configuration option as shown above and manual change.

Comment: Arokontham, thank you for your response, but .. I do not have that option - I do not have Type conversion settings where it is shown on your screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide an image of the same? And what integration runtime are you using?